# How to add certificate inside a dind container, because it needs restart of docker

Tags: docker

I am first spinning up a docker container

```
docker run --rm -it docker:19.03.13
#/
```

and then run the below commands

```
apk update

apk add --update openssl

openssl s_client -showcerts -connect registry.somedomain.com:443 < /dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ca.crt

cp ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

update-ca-certificates

systemclt restart docker    <--- THIS STEP HOW TO DO IN THE DOCKER CONTAINER

docker login registry.gitlab.com
```

Comment: You would need to do these steps in a custom Dockerfile starting `FROM docker:19.03`.  IME it's pretty unusual to want the `docker` Docker image; having multiple Docker daemons can quickly get confusing which one you're talking to, and there are tricky questions around volume mounts and publishing ports.

Answer (score -1):

first of all, why you need docker inside docker.

A pretty good post why you should not do docker in docker [link](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)

There are some use cases where we really need. looks like in your case. as its deals with certificates.

There are some good strategies define in this [link](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) here.

Also follow this video tutorial if you really wanted to use docker in docker [link](https://asciinema.org/a/378669)